# How can I press the iOS Keypad Key Programmatically in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm writing an iPad app that requires me to trigger the Space bar programmatically but I dont know how, Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.text = [textView.text stringByAppendingString: @" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly accessing the keyboard, just edit the text that the keyboard would have edited anyway... use

```
myTextView.text = [myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:@"New text to be added"];
```